# Como testar a aplicação com KivyMD?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Desenvolvi um pequeno app para testes que checa tanto o status da bateria quanto se o telefone está sendo carregado.

O app está rodando local a partir de `python main.py`, porém quando instalo ele no Android Studio *emulator*, o software inicializa e fecha.

**Atualização**

O pacote para o Android está sendo gerado com o [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer)

**buildozer.spec** (somente configurações)

```
[app]
title = My Test
package.name = mytest
package.domain = org.test
source.dir = .
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas
source.exclude_exts = spec
version = 0.1
requirements = python3, kivy==2.0.0, kivymd==0.104.1, sdl2_ttf == 2.0.15
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png
orientation = portrait
osx.python_version = 3
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1
fullscreen = 0
android.permissions = BATTERY_STATS
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

[buildozer]
log_level = 2
warn_on_root = 1
```

**Fim da atualização**

Já entendi que o problema está quando uso o [kivimd](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD), com o [kivy](https://github.com/kivy/kivy) funcionou.

Segue o código

**mytest.kv**

```
#:import MDLabel kivymd.uix.label
#:import MDBoxLayout kivymd.uix.boxlayout
#:import MDFloatLayout kivymd.uix.floatlayout
#:import MDTextButton kivymd.uix.button

<Page>:
    lbl1: lbl1
    lbl2: lbl2
    MDFloatLayout:
        MDTextButton:
            center: root.center
            size_hint_y: None
            pos_hint: {'y': .5}
            text: "Battery Status"
            on_press: root.get_status()
        MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            pos_hint: {'y': .1}
            MDLabel:
                text: "Is Charging?"
            MDLabel:
                id: lbl1
                text:
            MDLabel:
                text: "Percentage"
            MDLabel:
                id: lbl2
                text:
```

**main.py**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

from plyer import battery


class Page(MDBoxLayout):

    def get_status(self, *args):
        self.lbl1.text = str(battery.status['isCharging'])
        self.lbl2.text = str(battery.status['percentage']) + "%"


class MyTest(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Page()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyTest()
    app.run()
```

**Nota**: Substituindo de `kivymd` para `kivy` e substituindo de MD para , funciona.

Caso precisem de mais informações, favor comentar o post.

Comment: Para quem votou negativamente nesta questão, poderia me dizer o motivo para que eu possa melhorá-la?

Comment: desculpa, não entendi. Você já resolveu o seu problema? Em caso afirmativo, responda sua própria questão para ficar no formato Q&A, em vez de adicionar notas à pergunta. Está difícil entender da forma como está.

Comment: @Lucas. O problema **NÃO** está resolvido. Você conhece do processo de desenvolvimento para mobile usando o framework Kivy? O KivyMD é do mesmo grupo de desenvolvedores do Kivy. O que coloquei na questão é usando o framework Kivy está funcionando, mas com o KivyMD não. Porque o KivyMD? Boa pergunta. Ele traz facilidades para o layout.

Comment: Compreendo que faz tempo que a pergunta existe, e provavelmente você já resolveu, mas acaso a duvida "como testar?" permaneça, sugiro usar o `buildozer android debug deploy run logcat` para obter o logcat, e também usar o AndroidStudio, tendo o emulador habilitado a depuração USB. Sobre o problema, um detalhe que notei é que no `requirements=` você não adicionou o `plyer`, e isso é exigido quando vai fazer o deploy para Android, como é informado em: https://pypi.org/project/plyer/

Comment: @Syzoth agradeço a resposta. Desisti do Kivy e passei a "brincar" com o `react native` usando `expo` como framework. Bem mais tranquilo. Quem sabe um dia não volto para o Kivy. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Ok, entendo. Considerando que o problema aparente foi a falta do pacote plyer no buildozer.spec e/ou impossibilidade de confirmar se foi mais algo, irei fechar a pergunta como não pode ser reproduzido, a não ser que acredite que tenha algo que será útil de fato a outros usuários da comunidade. Até breve.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema: uma simples aplicação que não funcionava no android com o com kivymd, mas que funcionava com kivy. Consegui solucionar o problema alterando no buildozer.spec o requirements (de acordo com o demo kitchen_sink no github):

**requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip,certifi,pillow**

Onde está comentado: "(str) Custom source folders for requirements. Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes" retire o comentário e altere de kivy para kivymd:

**requirements.source.kivymd = ../../kivymd**